# Is there a term for someone who loves cute things?

Tags: single-word-requests

Such as arctophile or entomophile? Looking for something more formal sounding than 'cuteophile' or something similarly made up.

Comment: *Cuteophile*, though sounds cute, just cannot be, per rules of grammar/ linguistics conventions. A fine question for sure.

Comment: @Kris: Agreed, a tough nut to crack. I tried looking up "hearts rainbows unicorns" in a [reverse dictionary](http://onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=hearts+rainbows+unicorns), just to see what would happen. I found many interesting words – like Strzyga, Koosalagoopagoop, and Billy Bob Thornton – but many were not related to anything cute. I did find one candidate for the O.P.: _Binbealean_ (Binbeal is the Aboriginal god of rainbows). Example usage: _When I saw my daughter dotting her i's with small hearts, I admonished her. "Your handwriting is too Binbealean," I said._

Answer (score 7):

While not a perfect fit, a person who likes *beautiful* things would be an [aesthete](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aesthete).

In Japan — the home of all things cute and cuddly-wuddly — the term [kawaii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawaii), meaning *cute*, *lovable*, *adorable*, etc., "has become a prominent aspect of Japanese popular culture, entertainment, clothing, food, toys, personal appearance, behavior, and mannerisms". It has now [entered the English dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kawaii) as a loanword. People often talk about the "kawaii syndrome" affecting all of Japan. That said, a *kawaiiphile* sounds just as made up as *cuteophile*. Depending on context, you might be able to *stretch* kawaii-[otaku](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/otaku) (otaku is another loanword) to imply an obsessive interest in cute things.

Then there's [agalmatophilia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agalmatophilia) which involves "sexual attraction to a statue, doll, mannequin or other similar figurative object".

Comment: "Kawaiophile" would be a useful word to have in English :) but unfortunately its meaning wouldn't be very guessable to people who don't know the root word...

Comment: @alcas Agreed. But its entry into the dictionary as well as the ever-rising popularity of anime etc. should help. Then again, I expect that _kawaii_ will largely be misspelt/mispronounced to mean _kowai_ :|

Answer (score 5):

According to [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/definitionlookup?type=begin&q=dainty&target=greek) the Ancient Greek φιλόλιχνος, *philolichnos* meant "loving dainties, lickerish, dainty", so turning it around we'd get: *lichnophile*.

In Modern Greek, according to a correspondent at [wiki.answers.com](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_say_cute_in_Greek), "Cute is χαριτωμένο (haritomeno) which can be applied to both soulless objects (teddy bears, dresses etc.) and living beings (humans, dogs, cats etc.)", which would yield *charitomenophile*.

It would be interesting to know whether *lichnophilia* (or *charitomenophilia*) is clinically related to [Acquired Cuteness Disorder](http://mnm.hubpages.com/hub/Curing-ACD).

Comment: Lol at ACD! (before checking out the link, that is.)

Answer (score 2):

The term **sentimentalist** is somewhat broader, but may well encompass the concept you are seeking.  See *[sentimentality](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sentimentality)*.

The term *kitsch* is often used to describe objects that others might characterize as *cute*. See this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kitsch) that discusses sentimentality and kitsch (among many other things).

Comment: sent*a* or sent*i*?

Comment: @coleopterist Once again my sloppy typing betrays me. At least I spelled it right in one instance out of three. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of names, but if you're looking for a name like "otaku" or "weeaboo", there are sadly no names. I love Kawaii things myself, so I would suggest making up your own name. Try "Kawaiiboo" or "Kawaiiku".